# Internal error while connecting to hadoop dfs

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin, mapreduce

I built an eclipse plugin for hadoop-2.3.0. Bundle-classpath is

```
Bundle-classpath: classes/, 
lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/hadoop-auth-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/hadoop-common-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/hadoop-hdfs-${hadoop.version}.jar,
lib/protobuf-java-${protobuf.version}.jar,
lib/log4j-${log4j.version}.jar,
lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar,
lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar,
lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar,
lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar,
lib/commons-collections-${commons-collections.version}.jar,
lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar,
lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar,
lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar,
lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar,
lib/guava-${guava.version}.jar,
lib/netty-${netty.version}.jar
```

I added built jar file hadoop-eclipse-plugin.jar in eclipse\plugins. I am using Eclipse kepler sr2 package. On trying to create a hdfs and connect ..it is generating an internal error-->

```
An internal error occurred during: "Map/Reduce location status updater". org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
```

What might have cause this error and how to resolve it? Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Have you used Split/Join method of StringUtils or any other items of its API refer http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: @tom I only tried to create a hdfs...

Comment: Post your code for creating HDFS and Connecting it.